# Why did Slack abort magic link?

Tags: login, password-reminder, password-change

In the past, if I forgot my password, either on app or desktop, Slack asked me to provide my email, then it would send a `magic link` to my email, then I just click on it and logged in.

That UX seemed really smooth to me. Now they killed that option, and when I forgot password, they just sent me a link to reset password.

Why do they change that? (Did the old way pose a security risk?)
or it's just an opinionated choice?

Comment: Did you ask Slack why they did it? We can only guess the reason, which most likely even isn't UX related at all.

Comment: Did they actually abandon the magic link? This URL suggests they still have it: https://slack.com/help/articles/212681477-Sign-in-to-Slack

Comment: https://slack.com/signin#/signin offers me the choices of Google SSO, Apple SSO, or an email address with a description "We’ll email you a magic code for a password-free sign in. Or you can sign in manually instead."  It seems to me that they still support magic codes.

Comment: If you follow that link, and try really inputting your email, now they will send you a code to your email, you have to punch in the code in their sign-in page. In the past, they just sent you a link, you clicked on it then you would be logged-in. It's more convenient (yet same safety level).